# How to merge multilevel (i.e. MultiIndex) dataframes?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

What's the python/panda way to merge on multilevel dataframe on column "t" under "cell1" and "cell2"?

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df1 = pd.DataFrame(np.arange(4).reshape(2, 2), 
               columns = [['cell 1'] * 2, ['t', 'sb']])
df2 = pd.DataFrame([[1, 5], [2, 6]], 
           columns = [['cell 2'] * 2, ['t', 'sb']])
```

Now when I tried to merge on `"t"`, python REPL will error out

```
ddf = pd.merge(df1, df2, on='t', how='outer')
```

What's a good way to handle this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One solution is to drop the top level (e.g. `cell_1` and `cell_2`) from the dataframes and then merge.

If you want, you can save these columns to reinstate them after the merge.

```
c1 = df1.columns
c2 = df2.columns
df1.columns = df1.columns.droplevel()
df2.columns = df2.columns.droplevel()
df_merged = df1.merge(df2, on='t', how='outer', suffixes=['_df1', '_df2'])
df1.columns = c1
df2.columns = c2

>>> df_merged
   t  sb_df1  sb_df2
0  0       1     NaN
1  2       3       6
2  1     NaN       5
```

Comment: Thanks! It merged pretty well.

Answer (score 6):

```
pd.merge(df1, df2, left_on=[('cell 1', 't')], right_on=[('cell 2', 't')])
```